# Accidentally Deleted Admin Menu Items

Tags: routes

Hi i hope someone can offer me a bit of advice here. I seem to have deleted all my admin menu items. Is there a way to restore them without losing any data on my site?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu items are probably still there but disabled. In Drupal 6, navigate to *admin/build/menu-customize/navigation* and check if your administrative menu items are enabled. In Drupal 7 the path is *admin/structure/menu/manage/management*.

If you re-enable any menu items, make sure you scroll to the bottom of the page and hit the Save Configuration button to save your changes.

Comment: The OP is saying that he seems to have deleted the administrative menu items. In which way does clearing the cache help?

Comment: Thanks. I was imagining the OP damaged menu links and resetting the menu cache would fix it. That would be unlikely from the UI though, so the menu items are probably just disabled, in which case resetting the cache will not help. I'll change the answer.

Comment: Thanks Keith. you where right. they where still there. i found them again. I think clearing the cache helped. thanks for your input too kiamlaluno.